# Installing App via Android Studio reverts back my old app save state (WebView LocalStorage)

Tags: android, android-studio, local-storage, savestate, xiaomi

I am currently deploying a web app to my own physical Xiaomi Mi Note 10 device with Android Studio, built with capacitor. But everytime i install a new version to my phone, it reverts back an old save state, including old LocalStorage values in Android WebView.

I already wiped out data of the app manually and even uninstalled it, but still, with every new installation via USB the old save state gets restored. I restarted my Android phone and Mac device which im using, still this happens. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!!

Comment: Have your tried the `Clear Data` option which is available in the Android settings? That must clear all the local storage available in `/data/data/your.package.name`. Other local storage you might have in the public accessible directory might have to be done manually

Comment: @gtxtreme yes, like i said, i wiped app data from the device + uninstalled it. This indeed deletes all LocalStorage data und set the app back to factory settings. But after an install via Android Studio this old save state is back. Also i choose `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project` in the `Build` section of Android Studio window. I really don't know why this happens, never experienced it before..